# Finding 3 lines on a plane such that the area of the triangle is $\sqrt{6}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Given $ H=\{(x,y,z) : -x+2y-z=2\} $

I'm trying to find the three sides of a triangle on H with the area of  $\sqrt{6}$

I guess I only need 2 perpendicular vectors on that plane with magnitudes $||v_1|| ||v_2||=2\sqrt{6}$ to define a right triangle which would be easier to manage but I'm not sure how to select them.

Comment: If you're fine with any triangle, that should do it. Get the normal vector of your plane, complete it into an orthogonal basis, the two new vectors are parallel to $H$, define $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$ collinear to these vectors. Then pick any point $A\in H$ and take the points $B=A+\mathbf v_1$ and $C=A+\mathbf v_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Consider the parallel plane $H_0$ given by the equation $-x+2y-z=0$ and the vector $v_1=(1,1,1)$ which lies in that plane. Then find a vector $v_2=(2a,a+b,2b)\in H_0$ such that $v_1\perp v_2$ that is $0=v_1\cdot v_2=3a+3b$ and $\|v_2\|=\frac{2\sqrt{6}}{\|v_1\|}=2\sqrt{2}$. The required triangle is given by $A=(0,1,0)$, $B=A+v_1$ and $C=A+v_2$.

Comment: That's interesting, but why is $A = (0,1,0)$ ?

Comment: Because $A\in H$. We are translating the triangle given by the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ from $H_0$ to $H$.

Comment: You are welcome!!